# Bluetooth Low Energy device to trigger webservice call

Tags: automation, bluetooth, notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy, characteristics

I am looking for a software or easy to use library where I can connect to a BLE device (simple button, like key finder) that could trigger http request upon click. 
I already have rest api available on my local network. I need to be able to call it from the device. It can be software for android or windows. Anyone has ideas?

Comment: Does https://ifttt.com/ fits your usecase?

Comment: Does http://flic.io fit your use case?

Comment: thanks for replies!
ifttt.com can be used later as I cannot call ifttt url webhook directly from my device. I need some middleware to capture the device click and trigger a http call based on that (e.g. call to ifttt).
flic.io - too expencive, I am using 2$ keyring, other ways called iTag, or BLE button